# regex with optional positive lookahead non-capturing group

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, capturing-group

How do I get the following code to not raise an AssertionError? I'm trying to capture the group with `xyz` in it and use an optional positive lookahead [non-capturing group](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#non-capturing-and-named-groups) `(?:</div>)?`, but I can't get it to work. What should my `pattern` be?

```
import re

s1 = '<div foo=bar>ABC xyz DEF</div><div>GHI</div>'
s2 = '<foo><bar>JKL xyz MNO</foo></bar><baz>PQR</baz>'
s3 = '<div>zyx</div>'

# pattern = r'(?:<div.*?>)?(.*?xyz.*?)(?:</div>)?'
# pattern = r'(?:<div.*?>)?(.*?xyz.*(?:</div>)?)'
pattern = pattern = r'(?:<div.*?>)?(.*?xyz.*?)(?:(?=</div>))'
m1 = re.findall(pattern, s1)
m2 = re.findall(pattern, s2)
m3 = re.findall(pattern, s3)

print(m1)
print(m2)
print(m3)

assert m1 == ['ABC xyz DEF']
assert m2 == ['<foo><bar>JKL xyz MNO</foo></bar><baz>PQR</baz>']
assert m3 == []
```

P.S. Feel free to edit the title of my question.

EDIT: I came up with this solution. It's not that elegant, but it works:

```
pattern = r'(?:<div.*?>)?(.*?xyz.*?(?=</div>)|.*?xyz.*)'
```

Comment: not sure why you need non-capturing group around the lookahead... `(?:(?=</div>))` can be replaced with `(?=</div>)`...  for `m2`, you get empty result because you are checking that `xyz` should always be followed by `</div>`

Comment: @Sundeep Yes, and it's not always followed by `</div>`. Hence my question :-)

Comment: @tommy.carstensen I don't understand _why_ you would want to do this, but give `((?:<(?!div\b)\w[^<>]*>)*[^<>]*xyz[^<>]*(?:</(?!div\b)\w[^<>]*>)*)` a try: [demo](https://regex101.com/r/sunwuW/1).

Comment: @oriberu I have also tried this in the same way. but this regex is not capturing this part <baz>PQR</baz>

Comment: @CoderX You're right; I guess that inclusion does not make sense to me either. :) A description of the problem in natural language would be nice, because so far I read it as _match xyz and enclosing tags unless they're divs_.

Comment: Here is one that seems to capture what you want and is a little more performant, though I still don't get it: `^(?:<div[^<>]*>)?(.*?xyz.*?)(?:</div>|$)`, [demo](https://regex101.com/r/sunwuW/2).

Comment: This one is more perfect.Thank you @oriberu

Comment: @oriberu This is absolutely correct: "match xyz and enclosing tags unless they're divs"